# Twitter Account Activity API - Webhook URL must be defined issue

Tags: node.js, twitter, chatbot

I have a nodejs chat bot app which to listens to direct messages from twitter account. It was created with stream API of twitter. Now we are trying to migrate to new twitter Account Activity API.

We have used this [package](https://github.com/super-ienien/twitter-webhooks) to do this. But we met with this issue "Webhook URL must be defined to create subscriptions". Actually we have set a Webhook URL and still we have this issue.

Is there anyone who have implemented Twitter Account Activity API successfully? I could use some help here.

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

if you haven't found an answer, [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard) (account-activity-dashboard) is a web app that will help get started with Twitter's premium [Account Activity API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/overview). The account-activity-dashboard will help you configure the webhook urls and the subscriptions.

[image: account-activity-dashboard]

You can also have a look at my [forked repo](https://github.com/james-muriithi/account-activity-dashboard) which i used to create [my twitter bot](https://twitter.com/quoted_replies)